# Limit the number of indexes in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm very new to this, I hope this question makes sense.
I have a while loop that appends a list each time it runs. Is it possible to set a maximum number of indexes on the list, so that the oldest entry will be deleted each time a new one is added?

Answer (score 4):

No. But a `collections.deque` should work fine.

```
>>> d = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
>>> d.append(1)
>>> d.append(2)
>>> d.append(3)
>>> d.append(4)
>>> d
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
```

Comment: `deque` is a good answer, and you got my upvote, but note that if your `deque` is large, and you need to access elements in the middle, that can get kinda slow (it's a linked list and needs to be traversed each time from the beginning to find the desired element).

Answer (score 3):

Use the mod operator.

```
for i in range(N):

    L.insert(i%MAX_SIZE, object_to_be_added)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using pop(0)

```
d = range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def additem(list,n,max=10):
    if len(list) + 1 > max:
       list.pop(0)
    list.append(n)

additem(d,10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
additem(d,11)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```